# Autothrottle CPU based on usage

Tags: cpu, windows-10, overclocking, multiplier

Is there a program that allows me to lower the CPU multiplier if the "utilization" goes above a certain percentage? My CPU overclocks fairly heavily (**using the multiplier and "turbo-boost"**), and if I run 100% CPU (like one CPU-heavy thread per core), it overheats fairly seriously. I'm sure it would auto-shutdown at 200F to protect itself, but I would like a way to pull the multiplier down automatically if it goes above a certain usage level (or temperature, I guess).

Intel Core i5-4690K @ 3.50GHz

Multiplier: 8 - 43, goes into Turbo above 35.

Comment: You can find that in your BIOS, but 200 degree!! i don't know, anyway there is a small program called "speedFAN" allows you to control the temperature and the power :)

Comment: I got 4 cores and they all run 180 - 190 under full load. Talking Farenheit, of course.

Comment: "Farenheit" that's better :) anyway @HoD he mention another good program "cpuid" give it a try

Comment: What CPU do you have? Modern Intel CPUs run quite cool, 150-160 fahrenheit should be the maximum you see with a properly installed cooler.

Comment: @HoD, Intel Core i5-4690K @ 3.50GHz

Comment: You *can* do this using Intel XTU, assuming you have a Z87 or Z97 board, given that your CPU is unlocked.

Answer (score 1):

Your CPU should do this automatically already. Try running http://www.cpuid.com/ while your CPU is being stressed. When it reaches critical temperatures it should downclock automatically unless you messed with the Intel Speedstep Technology / AMD SpeedStep settings.

Comment: I don't think I messed with any settings, except to change the fan curve, and set some basic settings to High Performance in the BIOS. At idle it runs around 50 **C**, and  under full load it runs up to 85 C, or above if I let it run. Tried CPUID, but it doesn't seem to downclock. (I figured I'd switch to C since that's what everyone seems to use.)

Answer (score 0):

#### [Intel Extreme Tuning Utility (XTU)](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/motherboards/desktop-motherboards/desktop-boards-software-extreme-tuning-utility.html) can be used to control clock rates, including reducing the maximum clock rate when more cores are in use.

- The Core i5-4690K has unlocked clock multipliers. Although this is usually used to overclock the CPU, this feature can also be used to limit the processor's clock speed as needed.
- Intel XTU can be used to reduce the maximum clock multipliers when more cores are in use. This can be used to mitigate overheating while not limiting single-thread performance. I'd suggest starting by setting the multipliers to 43/40/37/35 (1 to 4 active cores), and adjusting from there as needed.
- Alternatively, you can undervolt the processor to reduce power consumption heat output, especially in conjunction with reducing the clock multipliers. Doing this can introduce instability similar to that caused by overclocking, so you may need to experiment with the controls to obtain stable results. When done correctly, this can dramatically reduce processor temperatures.

#### Make sure the cooler is properly installed. If that doesn't help, you should consider replacing the thermal paste or CPU cooler.

- The real cause of the issues you're encountering is that the CPU cooler isn't able to remove enough heat from the processor. When properly cooled, a CPU should never overheat under load. An improperly installed cooler can significantly reduce cooling performance, resulting in excessive temperatures. Be sure the cooler is firmly attached and that there is thermal paste between the cooler and processor package.
- If that doesn't help, you'll need to upgrade the thermal solution. Changes as minor as replacing the thermal paste can significantly improve cooling capacity and prevent overheating. There are also many third-party CPU coolers available, ranging from large, high-performance air coolers to advanced liquid cooling systems.

Comment: I don't know what it means, but the temperature shoots up when I start something CPU intensive, and then drops almost as fast as the actual usage when I stop it.